Is every weakly locally compact and semiregular space also Baire?
It's known (see Theorem 34, p. 200 of MR 0370454, or Proposition 20.18, p. 538 of MR 1417259) that every weakly locally compact (each point has a compact neighborhood) and regular space is Baire, where Baire means the countable union of closed nowhere dense subsets has empty interior; equivalently, such that the countable intersection of open dense subsets is still dense.
Can regular be weakened to semiregular here? Note that a space is semiregular provided it has a basis $\mathcal{B}$ of open sets such that $\operatorname{int}(\operatorname{cl}(O)) = O$ for every $O \in \mathcal{B}$.

A potentially constructive example: https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000185 is known to be semiregular (but not regular) and compact, but is it Baire? (I believe so: each dense set contains all isolated points, which are dense in the space.)

Weakly locally compact is too weak a condition to require. For example, you can just take any semiregular but non-Baire space (say, the rationals), and adjoin a single point $\infty$ whose only neighborhood is the entire space. Then the resulting space is compact, semiregular, but non-Baire.

Thanks. Haven't thought about the details but I think you could even make this $T_1$ by giving $\infty$ co-finite neighborhoods? What about a Hausdorff example?

I don’t think cofinite neighborhoods work. Those will not be regular open sets since their closure is just the entire space. Hausdorff is too strong to require - any locally compact Hausdorff space is already regular.

@DavidGao The resulting space can fail to be semiregular when the initial space contains a point whose unique neighborhood is the whose space.

@AlexRavsky Fair. But that’s the only obstruction. As long as the original space has no such point, the resulting space is semiregular.

You have an answer there David if you want the bounty. I'm not able to think of a $T_1$ example.

@StevenClontz I’ve been trying to think of a $T_1$ example as well, without success. I’m genuinely starting to think $T_1$ counterexamples don’t exist, but my proof attempt hasn’t succeeded yet either. Honestly, I got quite close to at least be able to say, if a $T_1$ counterexample actually exists, it has to be extremely weird. For now, I’ll post an answer to claim the bounty, and I’ll continue thinking about the $T_1$ case.

After thinking about a $T_1$ counterexample for more than a week (and so many times when I falsely thought I either found one or proved one cannot exist), I've finally constructed a $T_1$ counterexample. Here it is:
Recall first that regular open sets of a topological space $Y$ form a Boolean algebra under the meet operation $U \wedge V = U \cap V$, the join operation $U \vee V = \text{int}(\overline{U \cup V})$, and the complementation operation $\neg U = \text{int}(U^c)$. (It is in fact even a complete Boolean algebra, but we will not be needing this fact.) We will denote this Boolean algebra by $R(Y)$.
Now, let $Y = \mathbb{R}$ equipped with the topology generated by Euclidean open sets and all sets of the form $r + \mathbb{Q}$, $r \in \mathbb{R}$. We note that this is, in fact, just the disjoint union of continuum many copies of $\mathbb{Q}$. We observe two facts regarding open intervals in $Y$:

By definition, any open interval $(r_1, r_2)$, $r_i \in \mathbb{R} \cup \{\pm\infty\}$ is still open in $Y$. Its closure is $[r_1, r_2]$ (minus the infinities, if one or both of the endpoints are infinite), whose interior is again $(r_1, r_2)$. Hence, $(r_1, r_2)$ is regular open.
More generally, consider a finite union of open intervals, which can be written as,

$$(r_1, s_1) \cup (r_2, s_2) \cup \cdots \cup (r_n, s_n); r_i, s_i \in \mathbb{R} \cup \{\pm\infty\}, r_1 < s_1 \leq r_2 < s_2 \leq \cdots \leq r_n < s_n, n \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$$
$\;\;\;\;\;\;$One observes that it is regular open iff no left endpoint of an interval coincides with the right endpoint of an interval, i.e., iff all inequalities in the above are strict.
We will consider the Boolean subalgebra $A$ of $R(Y)$ consisting of finite unions of open intervals that are also regular open, whose forms we have observed above. It is not hard to check that $A$ is indeed a Boolean subalgebra of $R(Y)$. Moreover, the join of $U, V \in A$ is simply $U \cup V$ with potentially finitely many points added (those points which are simultaneously left endpoints of some intervals in either $U$ or $V$ and right endpoints of some intervals in either $U$ or $V$), while the complement of $U$ is simply $U^c$ with endpoints of intervals removed.
We will make two crucial observations regarding $A$:

If $U_1, \cdots, U_n \in A$ are s.t. $\bigvee_{i=1}^n U_i = Y$, then $\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^n U_i\right)^c$ is finite and thus compact. Indeed, as has already been observed, $\bigvee_{i=1}^n U_i$ is simply $\bigcup_{i=1}^n U_i$ with potentially finitely many points added;
If $\mathcal{U}$ is an ultrafilter on $A$, then $\bigcap \mathcal{U} = \varnothing$. Indeed, assume to the contrary that $r \in \bigcap \mathcal{U}$. Then $(r, r + 1) \in A$. Recall that the closure of $(r, r + 1)$ is $[r, r + 1]$, which contains $r$. Any $U \in \mathcal{U}$ is an open neighborhood of $r$, so it must intersect $(r, r + 1)$. Hence, as $\mathcal{U}$ is an ultrafilter, $(r, r + 1) \in \mathcal{U}$ and $r \notin (r, r + 1) \supset \bigcap \mathcal{U}$, a contradiction.

Let the Stone space of $A$, i.e. the collection of ultrafilters on $A$, be denoted by $S(A)$. Let $X = Y \sqcup S(A)$. We shall equip $X$ with the topology defined as follows:

Any $r \in Y$ has a basis of neighborhoods all open neighborhoods of $r$ in $Y$, i.e., $Y$ is an open subspace of $X$;
Any $\mathcal{U} \in S(A)$ has a basis of neighborhoods all sets of the form $U \sqcup V_U$, where $U \in \mathcal{U}$ and $V_U = \{\mathcal{V} \in S(A): U \in \mathcal{V}\}$. In particular, $S(A)$ has the usual Stone space topology as its subspace topology inherited from $X$.

It is easy to check that this is indeed a well-defined topology.
Proposition: $X$ is meager and thus not Baire.
Proof: Let $A \subset Y = \mathbb{R}$ be a Vitali set, i.e., it contains exactly one representative from each coset in $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}$. $A$ is closed with no interior in $Y$ - this can be seen mostly easily by noting that, if $Y$ is regarded as the disjoint union of continuum many copies of $\mathbb{Q}$, then $A$ simply consists of one point from each copy of $\mathbb{Q}$. Then, for each $q \in \mathbb{Q}$, let $B_q = (q + A) \sqcup S(A)$. As $q + A$ is closed in $Y$ and $S(A)$ is closed in $X$, it is easy to check $B_q$ is closed in $X$. We note that $B_q$ has no interior. Indeed, $q + A$ has no interior in $Y$, which is an open subspace of $X$. And, for any $\mathcal{U} \in S(A)$, any open neighborhood of $\mathcal{U}$ must, by defintion, contain a nonempty open interval in $Y$. But $q + A$ contains no such open interval. Finally, we observe that $X = \bigcup_{q \in \mathbb{Q}} B_q$. $\square$
Proposition: $X$ is $T_1$.
Proof: We need to check, for any $x \in X$, the intersection of all open neighborhoods of $x$ is $\{x\}$. This is clear when $x \in Y$. When $X = \mathcal{U} \in S(A)$, the intersection of all open neighborhoods of $\mathcal{U}$ is given by,
$$\left(\cap_{U \in \mathcal{U}} U\right) \sqcup \left(\cap_{U \in \mathcal{U}} V_U\right) = \left(\cap_{U \in \mathcal{U}} U\right) \sqcup \{\mathcal{U}\}$$
As observed before, $\cap_{U \in \mathcal{U}} U = \varnothing$, so the result follows. $\square$
Proposition: $X$ is compact and thus weakly locally compact.
Proof: Let $\{X_i\}$ be an open cover of $X$ by basic open sets, i.e., $X_i$ is either an open subset of $Y$ or of the form $U_i \sqcup V_{U_i}$ for some nonempty $U_i \in A$. Note that all such $V_{U_i}$ must cover $S(A)$. Since $S(A)$, being a Stone space, is compact, there exists finitely many $U_{i_1}, \cdots, U_{i_n}$ s.t.,
$$S(A) = \bigcup_{k = 1}^n V_{U_{i_k}} = V_{\bigvee_{k = 1}^n U_{i_k}}$$
i.e., $\bigvee_{k = 1}^n U_{i_k} = Y$. As observed before, this implies $\bigcup_{k = 1}^n U_{i_k}$ is a cofinite subset of $Y$. Hence,
$$\bigcup_{k = 1}^n X_{i_k} = \left(\bigcup_{k = 1}^n U_{i_k}\right) \sqcup S(A)$$
is a cofinite subset of $X$. It easily follows that $\{X_i\}$ admits a finite subcover. $\square$
From this point onwards, we shall write $\text{int}$ to mean the interior of a set in $X$ and use an overline to mean the closure of a set in $X$.
Proposition: Let $r, s \in \mathbb{R}$, $r < s$, $t \in (r, s)$. Then $(r, s) \cap (t + \mathbb{Q}) \subset Y$ is regular open in $X$.
Proof: Let $Z = (r, s) \cap (t + \mathbb{Q})$. The closure of $Z$ in $Y$ is easily seen to be $[r, s] \cap (t + \mathbb{Q})$. For any $\mathcal{U} \in S(A)$, it is in the closure of $Z$ iff, for any $A \in \mathcal{U}$, $A \cap Z \neq \varnothing$. Let the collection of all such $\mathcal{U}$ be $V$. Thus,
$$\overline{Z} = ([r, s] \cap (t + \mathbb{Q})) \sqcup V$$
Clearly, $\text{int}(\overline{Z}) \supset Z$. Neither $r$ nor $s$ is in $\text{int}(\overline{Z})$. For any $\mathcal{U} \in V$, any open neighborhood of $\mathcal{U}$ contains a nonempty open interval in $Y$, but $\overline{Z}$ does not contain such an interval, so no $\mathcal{U}$ can be in $\text{int}(\overline{Z})$. Hence, $\text{int}(\overline{Z}) = Z$ and $Z$ is regular open. $\square$
Proposition: Let $U \in A$ be nonempty. Then $U \sqcup V_U$ is regular open in $X$.
Proof: $V_U = V_{\neg U}^c$ is closed in $S(A)$ and thus also in $X$. For any $\mathcal{U} \in S(A)$, it is in $\overline{U}$ iff for all $W \in \mathcal{U}$, $W \cap U \neq \varnothing$. This clearly holds when $U \in \mathcal{U}$. If $U \notin \mathcal{U}$, then $\neg U \in \mathcal{U}$. But then $\neg U \cap U = \varnothing$. Hence, $\mathcal{U} \in \overline{U}$ iff $U \in \mathcal{U}$, i.e., iff $\mathcal{U} \in V_U$. Therefore,
$$\overline{U \sqcup V_U} = \text{cl}^Y(U) \sqcup V_U$$
Clearly, $\text{int}(\overline{U \sqcup V_U}) \supset U \sqcup V_U$. Since $U$ is regular open in $Y$, no point in $\text{cl}^Y(U) \setminus U$ can be in $\text{int}(\text{cl}^Y(U) \sqcup V_U) = \text{int}(\overline{U \sqcup V_U})$. Thus, $\text{int}(\overline{U \sqcup V_U}) = U \sqcup V_U$ and $U \sqcup V_U$ is regular open in $X$. $\square$
Corollary: $X$ is semiregular.
Proof: Sets in the two propositions above form a basis of topology for $X$. $\square$

This looks great, thanks for your effort on this David.

Here is my comment, turned into an answer:
Let $X$ be any semiregular but non-Baire space with no focal point (i.e., a point $x \in X$ whose only neighborhood is the entirety of $X$), say, the rationals. Now, adjoin a single point $\infty$ to $X$ whose only neighborhood is the entire space. Then the resulting space is compact and semiregular, but non-Baire.

Thanks David! I'll award another bounty if you or someone else manages to find a $T_1$ example, or a proof one cannot exist.
